# Translation into English of first Mel'cuk publications

Tags: reference-request

Does anyone have copies of these papers English translations ?

Mel'cuk, LA. (1958). “O maSinnom perevode s vengerskogo na russkij”, Problemy Kibernitiki 1, 222-264 [English translation : “Translation from Hungarian into Russian”, JPRS/646, archives ATALA].

Mel'cuk, LA. (1960). “K voprosu o grammatiôeskom v jazyke-posrednike”, Masinnyj Perevod i Prikladnaja Linguistika 4, 25-451 [English translation : “The problem concerningthe “grammatical”, “in an intermediate language”, JPRS/8026, archives ATALA].

Mel'cuk, LA. (1961). “Nekotorye voprosy masinnogo perevoda za rubezom”, Institut Naucnoj Informacii 6, 1-44, Moskva, AN SSSR [English translation : “Some problems of MT abroad, USSR”, Reports at the conference on Information Processing, MT and Automatic Text Reading, JPRS/13135, archives ATALA].

Comment: Do English translations of those works actually exist? They may not. You might ask Mel'cuk directly, though.

Comment: Mel'cuk told me that he doesn't have the translations, but others do. That is the reason I posted this question

Comment: OK, I understand. But then, did he not tell you who might have them? If you succeed at locating them, please let me know. I'd like to take a look.

Comment: You should be able to get them via the ILL department of your library.  The JPRS reports for 1957-1995 have been digitized, the access is provided by Readex (subscription only).

Comment: @AlexB. Thank you!